# Avoid method not found for protocol methods

Tags: cocoa, polymorphism, protocols

My Cocoa AppDelegate contains a reference of type ID to it's main view. The reference is polymorphic because it may point to a subclass of PDFView or a subclass of NSImageView, depending on the origin of the view's image. Both view subclasses implement the same protocol, so my AppDelegate does not have to know what type of view it's dealing with. However, every time I call one of the protocol methods I get a warning that says "Instance method '-methodName' not found (return type defaults to 'id')". I can either ignore the warning or force the issue by using "performSelector:(@selector(methodName:)" to call the protocol method.

Is there something I can do (or should have done) to eliminate the warning without resorting to performSelector?

```
//FLAppDelegate.h
@interface FLAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    ...
    IBOutlet id _formImageView;  //type is FLPDFView* or FLImageView*
    …
}

//FLFormImageProtocol.h
@protocol FLFormImageProtocol <NSObject>
@required
- (void)        methodName;
@end

//FLPDFView.h
@interface FLPDFView : PDFView <FLFormImageProtocol>
@end

//FLImageView.h
@interface FLImageView : NSImageView <FLFormImageProtocol>
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type the instance variable with the protocol:

```
IBOutlet id<FLFormImageProtocol> _formImageView;
```